# How to find BOOT-SEL GPIO PIN?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, soc

I'm new to embedded linux and trying to explore it using Allwiner T113-i EVB.

Right now I'm struggling with boot process.

According to user manual BROM of SoC will try fetch boot code from SD card if Pin_Boot_Select != 0.

Due to lack of my experience i wasn't able to find those pins in documentation and on SoC.

Have anyone worked with Alwwiner's EVB ? Can you tell if I'm wrong ?

In https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-i_EVB_V1_0_20220507.pdf I can see that there are BOOT-SEL0 and BOOT-SEL1, but in PCB documentation i can't find it https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-I_EVB_V1_0_PCB.pdf

I'm apologizing in advance if my question seems strange or silly!

[image: image from documentation]

Link to User Manual - https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-i_User_Manual_V1.5.pdf

Link to DataSheet - https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-i_Datasheet_V1.4.pdf

Comment: Your question might better be posted at [SE/EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) than here. Anyway, would you mind to [edit] and add a link to documentation, please?

Comment: I added link to documentation @thebusybee

Comment: A bit OT: _Why_ in the first place do you want to access these pins?

Comment: I want to boot device from SD card with u-boot

Answer (score 0):

Such devices use the same pins for multiple functions, of course not all at the same time.

A text search revealed in the data sheet (table 4-3, page 34) that `BOOT-SEL0` is on `PC4` and `BOOT-SEL1` is on `PC5`.

The schematic on sheet 10 shows the connected parts.

Be aware that there is more to the boot process than just certain levels at the GPIO pins.

Comment: I added PCB scheme (https://whycan.com/files/202304/T113-I/T113-I_EVB_V1_0_PCB.pdf) and i can't find PC4 and PC5 on it (also i didn't manage to find it on board).
Is it correct that i should look for F5 pin ?

Comment: Did you follow the wires shown in the schematic? It seems as if users are _not_ supposed to apply levels to `BOOT-SEL`.

Comment: As I understood I can affect the PC4 pin through resistor R18. But I’m not so sure how should I apply signal to it. I find it after following wires